# Numpy - create ordinal categories embedding

Tags: python, numpy, ordinal

I've written the following code to `one-hot encode` a list of ints:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])

targets = np.zeros((a.size, a.max()))
targets[np.arange(a.size),a-1] = 1
targets
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

I would like to change the code, to better fit my ordinal class problem, so that the output would be:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`broadcasted-comparison`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(a[:,None]>np.arange(a.max())).astype(float)
```

Sample run -

```
In [47]: a = np.array([3,1,2,4]) # generic case of different numbers spread across

In [48]: (a[:,None]>np.arange(a.max())).astype(float)
Out[48]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

If there are many entries and with a small range of numbers in `a`, we can create all the possible combinations and then index with `a`-offsetted one -

```
np.tri(a.max(), dtype=float)[a-1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [79]: a = np.array([3,1,2,4])

In [80]: np.tri(a.max(), dtype=float)[a-1]
Out[80]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need `tril`, which gives you the lower triangle.
Create an array of any size with `np.ones()` (just as you use `np.zeros()`), and then run it through `np.tril()`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])

targets = np.ones((a.size, a.max()))
targets = np.tril(targets)
targets
```

Or even simpler, use `tri()`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])

targets = np.tri(a.size, a.max())
targets
```